# FAILED: Can't locate revision

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

When I run command

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Reconciliation and daily amount tables"
```

It gives me output:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Can't locate revision identified by '67ad9835cada'
  FAILED: Can't locate revision identified by '67ad9835cada'
```

What is the source for the problem?

Comment: try pip2 install alembic, python3 might be the default on your version of linux.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Thank you, but I resolve my problem: I shouldn't use `sudo`, when work with alembic, because then it try to find command in global, but I`m work in virtual env, so in my case, problem was with alembic revisions: in my database in `alembic_version` I have info about some revision, which(maybe) I delete. So I just clean that table and make revision.

Comment: @Klimenkomud hey, could you mark this question as resolved ? (answering your own question) thanks

Comment: @Ehvince Done, I post some useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with revision, which wasn't located in revisions script directory. If in some way you lost some revision - you can use command `alembic stamp 67ad9865deca`, where `67ad9865deca` revision identifier, which for your database is head of revisions(means if you have higher revision and you wan't to make that migrations). Or just clean tabla `alembic_version` in your DB, in this case you will tell to alembic that you don't make any migrations yet.